# Counting subcategories and ads in every subcategory mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

As the title say , i have two tables one for categories and other for ads

```
  ads table

  id  , cat_id 
   31 ,  16
   32 ,  16
   33 ,  2

  categories table

  id , tree 
  1 , 0
  2,  0
  6,  0
  13, 1
  16, 6
  17, 6
  18, 6
```

My wished result is

```
  category , num subcategories  , num ads
      1    ,   1                ,  0
      2    ,   0                ,  1
      6    ,   3                ,  2
```

I want just get where the tree is 0 (Main categories) .

Here is [**my fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/31f249)

Comment: MySQL has very poor support for hierarchical data structures (if you are using 8+, then please tag that).  Although this can be solved for the data you provide, a generic solution is rather more complicated.

Comment: Im using mysql 5.6.15 .

Comment: You have chosen wrong tools for the job. Looks like you are trying to hammer a nail with a screwdriver. You should have chosen graph database instead like Neo4j instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have only a 2-level hierarchy, then you can do it like this:

```
select
    y.category,
    coalesce(z.sub_category_count, 0)  as num_sub_categories,
    y.num_ads
from
    (
        select               -- combine the level-1 and level-2 ad counts by category
            x.category,
            sum(ad_count)            as num_ads
        from
            (
                select       -- count ads for level-1 categories, by category
                    a.id        as category,
                    count(b.id) as ad_count
                from
                    categories a
                    left outer join
                    ads b
                    on a.id = b.cat_id
                where
                    a.tree = 0
                group by
                    a.id
                union
                select       -- count ads for level-2 categories, by level-1 category
                    c.tree       as category,  
                    count(d.id)  as ad_count
                from
                    categories c
                    left outer join
                    ads d
                    on d.cat_id = c.id
                where
                    c.tree <> 0
                group by
                    c.tree
            ) x
            group by
                x.category 
    ) y
    left outer join
    (
        select       -- count sub_categories by category
            tree      as category,
            count(id) as sub_category_count
        from
            categories
        where
            tree <> 0
        group by 
            tree
    ) z
    on y.category = z.category
order by
    category;
```

Results:

```
+----------+--------------------+---------+
| category | num_sub_categories | num_ads |
+----------+--------------------+---------+
|        1 |                  1 |       0 |
|        2 |                  0 |       1 |
|        6 |                  3 |       2 |
+----------+--------------------+---------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

If your hierarchy goes to more than 2 levels then it will get more more complicated.

Comment: yes i have just two levels , cats , subcats , and ads. will try your answer when i come home. thanks. i have tried your answer here http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/31f249/2 and it works.

Comment: Thanks Ron , i guess im going with your solution as im familiar with and easier. thanks so much it works like a charm in my code.

Answer (score 0):

As others said, MySQL is probably not the best choice for this task. If you want to use it anyway, here is a possible solution using [Nested set model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model). Extend table `categories` with two additional integer fields, `lb` and `rb`, that will keep left and right boundary of the particular category. All subcategories of that category will need to have their interval `[lb, rb]` completely contained within the parent category interval. Thus, the table `categories` should look like:

```
id tree lb  rb
==============
1   0   11  14
2   0   9   10
6   0   1   8
13  1   12  13
16  6   2   3
17  6   4   5
18  6   6   7
```

and the query that returns your wished result is:

```
select id,
(select count(*) from categories where lb >= cat.lb and rb <= cat.rb and tree > 0) as num_subcategories,
(select count(*) from ads a join categories c on a.cat_id = c.id where lb >= cat.lb and rb <= cat.rb) as num_ads
from categories cat
where tree = 0;
```

Here is [fiddle](http://rextester.com/live/TLTV51532). Notice that inserts and deletions of categories would become more complicated, that is a tradeoff to get easy search through the whole hierarchy. Here is a procedure for insert:

```
drop procedure if exists insert_category;
create procedure insert_category(_id int, _parent_id int) 
begin
    declare _parent_rb int default null;    

    if _parent_id = 0 then
        set _parent_rb = 1;
    else
        select rb from categories where id = _parent_id
        into _parent_rb;
    end if;

    update categories set rb = rb + 2 where rb >= _parent_rb;   
    update categories set lb = lb + 2 where lb >= _parent_rb;

    insert into categories(id, tree, lb, rb) 
    values (_id, _parent_id, _parent_rb, _parent_rb + 1);
end;
```

To get the table categories filled as described above, just call this procedure multiple times:

```
call insert_category(1, 0);
call insert_category(2, 0);
call insert_category(6, 0);
call insert_category(13, 1);
call insert_category(16, 6);
call insert_category(17, 6);
call insert_category(18, 6);
```

HTH.

Comment: Hi , thanks for your answer, im trying to understand why and how you filled exactly those numbers in lb and rb . why exactly 9 and 10 in first row and so on, Looks interesting but i must insert new rows whith new categories .

Comment: @samirdaraf I arranged them so that all fit in, taking into account that category 1 is parent of 13 and 6 is parent of 16, 17 and 18. Insert and delete procedures are a bit complicated, you have to extend/shrink existing intervals.

Comment: @SamirDaraf I have updated my answer with insert procedure, hope it will be much clearer now. I have also updated the fiddle, so you can try it by yourself. Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi , i have tested your answer in the fiddle , and it works , im not familer with the precedure functions but im looking if i can merge it in my code. anyway thanks for giving answer , i will wait if it will come some easiest answer. btw strange for downvoting i have upvoted as it gives answer and explained.

Comment: @SamirDaraf Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048151/what-are-the-options-for-storing-hierarchical-data-in-a-relational-database
Two most popular options for storing hierarchical data in a relational database are Adjacency lists and Nested sets. Since MySQL until v8 does not support CTE for traversal, Nested sets are your best bet.